# What does the following line do exactly in Julia?

Tags: julia

what does exactly the following lines in Julia?

```
for i in range(1,length=length(parameterList))
    parameterList[i]["alfa"]= measures_list[i]
end
```

does it put, like in Java, or something different?

Comment: What do you mean by "does it put"? Is there a word missing from that sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This line means that most likely each entry of `parameterList` is a dictionary. Then in each of these dictionaries key `"alfa"` is assigned value `measures_list[i]`.

Other ways to write it not using `range` are for example:

```
for i in eachindex(parameterList)
    parameterList[i]["alfa"]= measures_list[i]
end
```

or

```
for (i, parameter) in enumerate(parameterList)
    parameter["alfa"]= measures_list[i]
end
```

or

```
foreach(parameterList, measure_list) do parameter, measure
    parameter["alfa"]= measure
end
```

or if you are sure that `parameterList` and `measures_list` have the same length:

```
for (parameter, measure) in zip(parameterList, measure_list)
    parameter["alfa"]= measure
end
```

(choose whatever you like best :))

Comment: Does it mean, thaf suppose "alfa" does not exist, then it is added to the list?

Comment: Yes a key-value pair is added to a dictionary (note - that `parameterList[i]` is not a list, but a dictionary). If such key existed a new value gets assigned. You can check if the key exists in the dictionary using the `haskey` function.